# Where are CMB or galactic photons travelling to?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, cosmic-microwave-background

I'd like to describe my problem in an example:
Let's say one "generation" of CMB photons reaches Earth and
the passing ones arrive at Mars ~20 min later.
As CMB is coming from all directions the photons of our 1st generation,
passing Mars first, arrive here ~20 min later in the same way.
At that time another generation passes Earth.
But that means photons of both generations are present at the same time.
If we generalize this, all generations of CMB are present at any time.
Are CMB and all other light going to nowhere? What do I missunderstand?

Comment: They're everywhere, and at every point, going in every direction.

Comment: There aren't really "generations" of CMB photons; to a good approximation, all CMB photons were emitted at the same time. However, the CMB photons where emitted *everywhere* at the time of last scattering. Therefore, a CMB photon you observe now, came from a place 20 light-minutes closer to you, than a CMB photon you will observe 20 minutes from now.